# How to pass argument to another jenkins build step

Tags: ssh, jenkins, continuous-integration

In Jenkins job i need to execute shell on jenkins machine. I use `Execute shell` step from there i get value, which have to be used in another step `Execute shell script on remote host using ssh`. I can't find way to pass that value...

Here is my jenkins job configuration:
[image]

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content of the file which constains the script:

```
echo "VERSION=`/data/...`"> env.properties
```

Path of the properties file:

```
env.properties
```

In shell script using ssh:

```
echo"... $VERSION"
```

Something like this works for the build, maybe here works too.

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected. In inject environments variables i indicated env.properties file, and shell script accessed $VERSION property. Thanks!